GND in multi-layer PCB
Imagine a simple 4 layer PCB with this stack layout:

SIGNAL
SIG-GND
PWR-GND
POWER

Layer two and three must be connected together at the end, so the two GND planes purpose is "just" for signal integrity where SIGNAL return path is nearest as possible.
What is the best practice to interconnect these two ground planes  preserving signal integrity?

"what is the meaning to have two different GND planes?" Well didn't you choose to have it that way? It's pretty rare, but for some reason you made that choice. I think you should tell us why, if you want to get a better answer.

I did it for separating return paths for signals and return paths for power sources.

Ok but do you see how it's difficult to answer "What is the meaning of..." when you have already decided the meaning? Maybe I don't understand what your end goal here is.

i simplified reformulating

I see two hyphens separating three items; where is the fourth layer?  Also "two and three" are referring to which? -- is this a zero- or one-based list?  || Are you familiar with the practice of "via stitching"?

The best way is connect them is to have one layer. Maybe you should explain what the problem or goal is, which parts or areas are the concern.

Best practice is to have a single ground plane, and to layout your components carefully so that PSU returns do not corrupt signals.

@ErikFriesen the idea was to split GND planes for optimizing SI. Ideally, these two ground planes would be neither be interconnected each other. Practically is not possible.     So GND planes must be interconnected each other. The point where  to interconnect the two GND planes is not clear in order to preserve overall   SI
